# User Input going through list of Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, user-input

I am trying to have the output to return the previous list instead of the same list. I created two lists, one for the new entry for every search and one to save the search to be used if the User input is 'back'.

```
string = "Sam 23 pizza cola park\nJoe 19 hamburger sprite\nMike 25 cake fanta museum\nBen 22 pie"


a = ['Name','Age','Food','Drink','Place']
b = ['Name','Age','Food','Drink']
c = ['Name','Age','Food',]

e =[]
f = []
l = []   
pre = []   

#Attaching keys with their values based off the number of values(words) they have:
for line in string.splitlines():
    words = line.split(' ')
    f.append(words)
    if (len(words) == 5):
       e.append((dict(zip(a, line.split()))))
    elif (len(words) == 4):
         e.append((dict(zip(b, line.split()))))
    else:
           e.append((dict(zip(c, line.split()))))
    
search = input("Enter key: ")       # Get first input
while search != "q":                # If input equals to q, quit
    entry = search.split()          # Split the search into a list if multiply keys are inputted
    if 'back' in entry and len(pre) == 0 :   # return the orginal data list
        print('\n',e,'\n')                  

    elif 'back' in entry and len(pre) != 0:     # Return previous entry
        print('\n',pre,'\n')
        pre.clear()                             # Clear the previous entry after printing 
    else:
        pre.clear()                             # Clear the previous entry
        for val in e:                           # Look for Name in List
            for word in entry:
                if word in val["Name"]:
                        l.append(val)
                        pre.append(val)
    if len(l) != 0:                             # If the the output list contains something print it
        print('\n',l,'\n')

    l.clear()                                   # Clear for the new entry
    search = input("Enter key: ")               # Next Search
else:
   print("\ngoodbye. . .")                      # Print Goodbye if input was q
```

From my script I get:

```
Enter key: Sam

 [{'Name': 'Sam', 'Age': '23', 'Food': 'pizza', 'Drink': 'cola', 'Place': 'park'}] 

Enter key: Joe Mike

 [{'Name': 'Joe', 'Age': '19', 'Food': 'hamburger', 'Drink': 'sprite'}, {'Name': 'Mike', 'Age': '25', 'Food': 'cake', 'Drink': 'fanta', 'Place': 'museum'}] 

Enter key: back

 [{'Name': 'Joe', 'Age': '19', 'Food': 'hamburger', 'Drink': 'sprite'}, {'Name': 'Mike', 'Age': '25', 'Food': 'cake', 'Drink': 'fanta', 'Place': 'museum'}]
```

I would like to get

```
Enter key: Sam

 [{'Name': 'Sam', 'Age': '23', 'Food': 'pizza', 'Drink': 'cola', 'Place': 'park'}] 

Enter key: Joe Mike

 [{'Name': 'Joe', 'Age': '19', 'Food': 'hamburger', 'Drink': 'sprite'}, {'Name': 'Mike', 'Age': '25', 'Food': 'cake', 'Drink': 'fanta', 'Place': 'museum'}] 

Enter key: back

 [{'Name': 'Sam', 'Age': '23', 'Food': 'pizza', 'Drink': 'cola', 'Place': 'park'}]
```

I believe it has something to do with how I save the previous entry but not sure how to go back it. Any help to lead me to the correct approach would be helpful

Comment: You don't need the conditions based on `len(words)`. `zip()` doesn't require both lists to be the same length, it uses the shorter length.

Comment: You're emptying `pre` before each search. So it always contains the last result, not the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two variables. One for the last result, another for the 2nd-to-last result. Before each search, copy the last to the 2nd-to-last. When they enter `back`, print the 2nd-to-last.

```
string = "Sam 23 pizza cola park\nJoe 19 hamburger sprite\nMike 25 cake fanta museum\nBen 22 pie"

keys = ['Name','Age','Food','Drink','Place']

e =[]
f = []
l = []
pre = []
pre_pre = []

#Attaching keys with their values based off the number of values(words) they have:
for line in string.splitlines():
    words = line.split()
    f.append(words)
    e.append(dict(zip(keys, words)))

search = input("Enter key: ")       # Get first input
while search != "q":                # If input equals to q, quit
    entry = search.split()          # Split the search into a list if multiply keys are inputted
    if 'back' in entry and len(pre_pre) == 0 :   # return the orginal data list
        print('\n',e,'\n')

    elif 'back' in entry and len(pre_pre) != 0:     # Return previous entry
        print('\n',pre_pre,'\n')
        pre.clear()                             # Clear the previous entry after printing
    else:
        pre_pre = pre
        pre = []                             # Clear the previous entry
        for val in e:                           # Look for Name in List
            for word in entry:
                if word in val["Name"]:
                        l.append(val)
                        pre.append(val)
    if len(l) != 0:                             # If the the output list contains something print it
        print('\n',l,'\n')

    l.clear()                                   # Clear for the new entry
    search = input("Enter key: ")               # Next Search
else:
   print("\ngoodbye. . .")                      # Print Goodbye if input was q
```